# Why does rsync give different output between rsyncing to a USB flash drive versus a hard disk?

Tags: linux, hard-drive, usb, backup, rsync

How come rsync gives different outputs when there are no files for rsync to transfer, meaning (`xfr#0`) with rsync from hard disk to hard disk versus rsync from USB flash drive to hard disk?

Using:

- Ubuntu 20.04.4 LTS (Focal Fossa).
- rsync  version 3.2.3  protocol version 31.

All directories are synced, up to date. Thus no files for rsync to transfer, meaning (`xfr#0`) when running rsync a second time.

Example 1 script:

```bash
src1='/media/u3/d_HDD931GB/TemP'  
dest='/media/u3/s_HDD931GB/1/TemP'   
tput setaf 2  ; echo "$src1   $dest" ;   
tput setaf 1  ; test ! -d "$src1" && echo "ErrorS" ; test ! -d "$dest" && echo "ErrorD" ; tput setaf 2 ;  
time rsync -ah --delete-before --info=progress2 "$src1/" "$dest" --out-format='%t %i %C %b %n %l ' ;  
echo "$src1   $dest" ; echo  ;
```

Example 1 output:

```bash
/media/u3/d_HDD931GB/TemP   /media/u3/s_HDD931GB/1/TemP   
              0   0%    0.00kB/s    0:00:00 (xfr#0, to-chk=0/5)  

real    0m0.054s  
user    0m0.004s   
sys     0m0.010s  
/media/u3/d_HDD931GB/TemP   /media/u3/s_HDD931GB/1/TemP
```

The above is expected. A minimal rsync output when rsync from hard disk to hard disk and rsync has no files to transfer (`xfr#0`) because hard disk is already synced.

But a long list of files with rsync output when rsync from USB flash drive to hard disk when USB flash drive has no files to transfer (`xfr#0`) because USB flash drive is already synced and up to date.

Why a such a long list of files with USB flash drive?

Example 2 script, USB flash drive:

```bash
src1='/media/u3/F_4GBusb'    
dest='/media/u3/d_HDD931GB/Rare/Sophos'   
tput setaf 3  ; echo "$src1   $dest" ;   
tput setaf 1 ; test ! -d "$src1" && echo "ErrorS" ; test ! -d "$dest" && echo "ErrorD" ; tput setaf 3 ;  
time rsync -ah --delete-before --info=progress2 "$src1/" "$dest" --out-format='%t %i %C %b %n %l ' ;  
echo "$src1   $dest" ; echo  ;
```

Example 2 output, USB flash drive:

```bash
/media/u3/F_4GBusb   /media/u3/d_HDD931GB/Rare/Sophos  
2022/07/30 20:11:46 .d...p.....                                  0 ./ 4096  
2022/07/30 20:11:46 .f...p.....                                  0 words.txt 4862992  
2022/07/30 20:11:46 .f...p.....                                  0 virtualbox.odt 22142  
etc ...  
etc ...  
etc ...  
etc ...  
etc ... listing 502 files  
etc ...  
              0   0%    0.00kB/s    0:00:00 (xfr#0, to-chk=0/502)  

real    0m0.088s  
user    0m0.015s  
sys     0m0.012s  
/media/u3/F_4GBusb   /media/u3/d_HDD931GB/Rare/Sophos
```

Why does rsync give different output when there are no files for rsync to transfer, meaning (`xfr#0`) with rsync from hard disk to hard disk versus rsync from USB flash drive to hard disk?

Output of `sudo fdisk -l`:

```bash
Disk /dev/sdb: 3.75 GiB, 4005560320 bytes, 7823360 sectors  
Disk model: Flash Disk        
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes  
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes  
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes  
Disklabel type: dos  
Disk identifier: 0x6f20736b
```

Output of `lsblk -f`:

```bash
sdb    vfat     F_4GBusb
```

---

More commands `--modify-window=7` did not work.

Same problem. Over 500 files listed with no rsync transfers.
2 directories are in sync, so why List 500+ files?

```bash
time rsync -ah --delete-before --modify-window=7 --info=progress2 "$src1/" "$dest" --out-format='%t %i %C %b %n %l '
```

Recall 2 directories are in sync. Thus no rsync transfers.
Meaning `(xfr#0, to-chk=0/503)`

And `-c` did not work, same problem.

```bash
time rsync -ahc --delete-before --modify-window=7 --info=progress2 "$src1/" "$dest" --out-format='%t %i %C %b %n %l '
```

And this did not work, just `-c` no `--modify-window=7`.

```bash
time rsync -ahc --delete-before --info=progress2 "$src1/" "$dest" --out-format='%t %i %C %b %n %l '
```

---

rsync from hard disk to hard disk is working as expected
when `file.txt`` is deleted from destination drive.

```bash
2022/07/31 01:05:08 >f+++++++++ ad7d6d11c4cf0b771ade515eee5465c8 8945 file.txt 8902     
          8.90K   0%    0.00kB/s    0:00:04 (xfr#1, to-chk=0/121057)
```

Comment: Odd. Is the USB flash drive formatted in a specific format or partitioning scheme?

Comment: State the Terminal commands to run for Partitioning scheme and Format of USB flash drive, so I can report back with Terminal output.

Comment: The output of `fdisk -l` (or `sudo fdisk -l`) should be fine. The last column will be the “Type.”

Comment: You can use `lsblk -f` to print the partitions and the filesystem they are formatted to.

Comment: Thanks for the added info! It seems to me that the issue is the timestamp accuracy on the DOS formatted USB flash drive is not the same as the hard drive on you Linux system. I believe the solution is to set `--modify-window` to `--modify-window=1` in your Rysnc command to the USB flash drive and try again. More info [here](https://superuser.com/a/919225/167207) as well as [here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/267208/30848). Or you can just add the `-c` that compares files via checksum which might be slower, due to checksum calculation, but is more accurate.

Comment: Update, See bottom of Question.

Answer (score 11):

The `-i` "itemize" output tells you exactly why they're not in sync: `p` in `.f...p.....` means that rsync considers the *file permissions* to be different between source and destination.

File permissions will often be different because the FAT filesystem that's used by your USB stick is **unable to store them** – even after rsync has tried to chmod() the destination files to something else, vfat always reports the exact same modes and ownership that the mount options tell it to report.

Use `--no-perms` to disable synchronizing file permissions, which is otherwise enabled by `-a`.

Comment: Correct.  Use ```--no-perms``` to disable synchronizing file permissions formatted as FAT32 for USB flash drive, stick.

Comment: For clarity about Permissions, attribute example : Source file attrib = ```-rw-r--r-- 0 1000 1000``` and Target file attrib = ```-rwxrwxrwx 0 1000 1000``` thus ```--no-perms``` is working, meaning ```time rsync -ah --delete-before --no-perms --info=progress2 "$src1/" "$dest" --out-format='%t %i %C %b %n %l ' ```

Comment: Ahhh… So permissions were the issue? Good to know.